# Differences using Model::create between Laravel 5.4 and 5.8?

Tags: laravel

I have a project based on Laravel 5.8, where I store a model from a validated form Request, but I can't find out why I have to so to make it work :

```
public function store(CotisationRequest $request)
{
    $cotisation = new Cotisation();
    $cotisation->fill($request->except('_token'));

    if ($request->cheque) {
        $cheque     = Cheque::create($request->cheque);
        $cotisation->cheque()->associate($cheque);
    }

    $cotisation->save();

    return redirect()->route('cotisations.edit', ['cotisation' => $cotisation, 'membre' => $cotisation->membre]);
}
```

There is the model def :

```
class Cotisation extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'cotisations';
    public    $with       = ['cheque', 'especes'];
    public    $fillable   = [
        'membre_id', 'cheque_id', 'annee', 'speciale', 
'droits_entree',
        'cotisation','don', 'montant', 'mode_paiement', 'statut'
    ];
   ...
}
```

And here is the request :

```
class CotisationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'membre_id'             => 'exists:membres,id',
            'cotisation'            => 'min:0|lte:montant',
            'don'                   => 'min:0|lte:montant',
            'droits_entree'         => 'min:0|lte:montant',
            'montant'               => 'min:0|numeric',
            'cheque.montant'        => 'required_if:mode_paiement,CHQ|gte:montant',
            'cheque.emetteur'       => 'required_if:mode_paiement,CHQ',
            'cheque.banque'         => 'required_if:mode_paiement,CHQ',
            'cheque.numero'         => 'required_if:mode_paiement,CHQ',
            'cheque.date_emission'  => 'required_if:mode_paiement,CHQ|date|before_or_equal:today',
            'annee'                 => Rule::unique('cotisations')->where(function($q) {
                return $q->where('membre_id', $this->input('membre_id'));
            }),
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        return [
            'membre_id.exists' => 'Le membre n° :input n\'a pas été trouvé.',

            'cotisaton.min'  => 'La cotisation minimale est de 0€.',
            'cotisation.lte' => 'La cotisation doit être inférieure ou égale au montant total indiqué.',

            'don.min' => 'Le don minimal est de 0€.',
            'don.lte' => 'Le don doit être inférieur ou égal au montant total indiqué.',

            'droits_entree.min' => 'Le droit d\'entrée minimal est de 0€.',
            'droits_entree.lte' => 'Le droit d\'entrée doit être inférieur ou égal au montant total indiqué.',

            'cheque.montant.required_if' => 'Le montant du chèque est requis.',
            'cheque.montant.gte'         => 'Le montant du chèque doit être égal ou supérieur au montant total indiqué.',

            'cheque.emetteur.required_if' => 'L\'émetteur du chèque est requis.',

            'cheque.banque.required_if' => 'La banque du chèque est requis.',
            'cheque.numero.required_if' => 'Le numéro du chèque est requis.',

            'cheque.date_emission.required_if'     => 'La date d\'émission du chèque est requis.',
            'cheque.date_emission.before_or_equal' => 'La date d\'émission du chèque doit être antérieure ou égale à aujourd\'hui.',

            'annee.unique' => 'Une cotisation est déjà définie pour l\'année :input.',
        ];
    }
}
```

Here I have to create a new instance, then fill it. 
If I try to do the same the "::create" way, only some fields are filled, and I cannot find out why, since my fillable is correctly set.

Have you any idea ? Thanks for your help (the controller code now works, but I would just like to understand what is my mistake).

Answer (score 0):

I think $model->fill() can save relationship with array (relationship.attribute), not ::create

Answer (score 0):

```
//you only need:
$cotisation = Cotisation::create($request->all());

//you do not need to fill

if ($request->cheque) {
   $cheque     = Cheque::create($request->cheque);
   $cotisation->cheque()->associate($cheque);
   //place save inside of if statement since you only need to save if doing this
   $cotisation->save();
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships

Comment: the problem is that with create, some fields, which are validated are not populated, although I added them in $fillable.

Comment: so running the above code, if you place a dd($cotisation) after the if statement you get null values?

Comment: There is the result, maybe is it because of the $guarded attribute (which I have not defined) ? It is trimmed for simplicity.

    Cotisation {#256 ▼
      #attributes: array:4 [▼
        "annee" => "2019"
        "updated_at" => "2019-07-10 14:02:29"
        "created_at" => "2019-07-10 14:02:29"
        "id" => 3544
      ]
      #original: array:4 [▼
        "annee" => "2019"
        "updated_at" => "2019-07-10 14:02:29"
        "created_at" => "2019-07-10 14:02:29"
        "id" => 3544
      ]
    }

Comment: you are using fillable (a whitelist approach) so you don't need guarded (blacklist approach)

Comment: should just be able to remove that line. That variable doesnt need to be defined

Answer (score 0):

How dumb I was ! everything happened because of a __construct in my model, which bypassed the ::create method !